# If $P(A)$ is a set, $A$ is a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

I know from a ZFC axiom that if $A$ is a set then $P(A)$ (the powerset of A) is a set. 
Is it possible to prove the converse? Or is it an independence property?

Comment: If $A$ is not a set, then what does $\mathcal{P}(A)$ even mean?

Comment: $A$ could be a proper class

Answer (score 3):

The axioms of union and extensionanilty can be used to prove that if $B$ is a set, then $\cup B$ is also a set. Now consider $B=P(A)$.

Comment: Sum and powerset are inverses of each other, that suprised me when I first saw it, +1

Comment: @mzg147 They are not inverses of each other. Although $\bigcup \mathcal{P}(A) = A$ always, $\mathcal{P}(\bigcup A) = A$ is generally not true.

Comment: Right, one sided inverses.

Answer (score 1):

To get round the objections, rephrase your question as: Suppose B is a set and $\phi(x)$ a formula such that  $\forall s(s\in B \iff (\forall x\in s) \phi(x))$. Then is there a set A such that $B = P(A)$? And the answer is yes, $A = \bigcup B = \{x|\phi(x)\}$.